# Load knockoutjs component using javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components

What's the best way to load a ko component with JavaScript code instead of defining a custom element in html? I tried with ko.components.defaultLoader.load but my component constructor does not hit.
I double checked and the component appears to be registered.

Comment: `<div data-bind="component: { name: 'mycomp', params: { }}></div>`? `ko.components.register('mycomp', {viewModel: function(params) {...}, template: ''})`? If this doesn't answer your question, you should provide more details, like what exactly you want (a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) and why.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is function ko.components.get(componentName, callback). What this method does is ask the component loaders to resolve the component name until it finds one. If it doesn't find one, it will call callback(null). If it does fine one, it will call callback(componentDefinition), where componentDefinition is the object used to register the component, like { viewmodel: ..., template: ...}.

As far as I can tell, there isn't a ready made function which returns a "working" component. What you have to do after getting the componentDefinition object is something like:

1. convert the template into a DOM element
2. instantiate the viewmodel (if defined)
3. bind the viewmodel to the DOM element

Note that this is not straight away because templates and view models can be defined in several ways. 
I recommend looking at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/components/componentBinding.js and see how it's done here (from line 38).

I hope this works for you, otherwise you could consider other options, like dynamically creating a div element in code with a component binding where the component name and parameters are bound to properties of a view model. Then bind this view model to the div element you just created. This should work "code only" which much less code than the other route.