# Knockout-generated HTML to normal HTML

Tags: knockout.js

I have a complex web application that makes extensive use of knockout. Now, I want to transform a subset of the dynamic knockout-bound html to a static html representation, for example

```
<div data-bind="style : { width : mywidth} "/> /** mywidth = 40px
```

to

```
<div style='width:40px' />
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understand your question right you can use the developer tools to select the root element and copy the outer html Once the application is rendered

Comment: I want to do this in js only

Comment: Do you mind if the copy of the html has the original data-bind attributes on it as well as the updated styles etc?

Comment: Actually I want to remove the data-bind attr, I just realized the style attributes are already set and obtainable.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636776/how-to-load-a-knockoutjs-component-programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get hold of the current HTML rendered by getting hold of the parent element (`#wrapper` in this case), then creating a new DOM node and putting the HTML in it, iterating all elements and removing the `data-bind` attribute, finally reading the HTML back out of it again:

```js
var model = {
  mywidth: ko.observable(40),
  gethtml: function() {
    //Get current HTML
    var html = document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML;
    
    //Create "fake" element to hold it
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = html;
    
    //Loop all child elements in fake element
    var elements = d.getElementsByTagName('*');
    
    //remove data-bind from each
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].removeAttribute('data-bind');
    }
    
    //finally log the resulting HTML
    console.log(d.innerHTML);
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```css
div.ex {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="ex" data-bind="style: { width : mywidth() + 'px'}"></div>
</div>

<div>
  Set width: <input data-bind="value: mywidth">
  <button data-bind="click: gethtml">Log Current HTML</button>
</div>
```